# Jboss4.3 and ATG 9.4- Determining the jar in use when mulitple jars of same name are in the classpath

Tags: jar, jboss, atg

I have a question concerning jboss 4.3 and ATG 9.4.

I have a requirement to update axis.jar(1.4) for my application, I have made some changes to the jar and want to use mine. I have updated the MANIFEST.MF's ATG-Class-Path for my module and referred to the updated JAR present in lib/. My module is dependent on some modules like DAS, and other custom modules that have the same jar.

On JBOSS Startup, under the un-ordered CLASSPATH entries, I see all the jars being picked up (mine and the old versions from the dependent modules). I understand that the first one that loads will be the one in use for the application.

Can I be sure that the one in the ATG-Class-Path for my module is finally the one being used? Is there a way to prove that on run time, like adding something to the jar and printing that out to the logs, or some other decent way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check which jar is actually loaded go to the URL

host:port/dyn/dyn/whichversion.jhtml

and enter full name of any class that is supposed to be in your jar.
The page will show full path to the class file location.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use findclass utility in addition to whichversion.jhtml mentioned in the other answer.

```
host:port/dyn/dyn/findclass.jhtml
```

Enter the name of the class in the Class Name field and click Find Class. The utility accepts class names in several formats. For example:

```
atg.droplet.Cache
/atg/droplet/Cache.java
atg.droplet.Cache.class
atg/droplet/Cache.class
```

You can find the information about this here.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0607usingthefindclassutility01.html